# How do I build a large jquery-based website?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, mustache

I want to start a new project, a large jquery application/website. I want the site to function a lot like twitter or github, very dynamic, very fluid/smooth, etc...

My problem is I don't know where to start. I've read countless blog posts, investigated many JS frameworks / templating & MVC type systems.

When I write JS code, should I put everything into a single file? Or should I breakout each plugin I write into separate files and then use a JS loader like Respond.JS?

I think I need a templating system though to get the hashtag navigation to work, so I'm looking at either Backbone.JS or Mustache/Handlebars.JS

Does anyone have a starting point for this? Perhaps a boilerplate solution / development pattern that I can follow?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I doubt any of use can tell you what JavaScript frameworks you should use without a working knowledge of the project itself.

Comment: well... perhaps we can work something out. I would hope that generally speaking the application itself shouldn't matter. Its nice to know more, but I'm trying to speak generically here. I don't think approaching one application versus another based on the function/purpose makes a lot of sense. Every application given the constraints I provided (JS frameworks) should have similar starting points at least. For sake of conversation, imagine I'm going to build a GMail clone.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends very heavily on your definition of "large" and what kinds of components you are deploying. I find it highly doubtful that we'd be able to know your environment well enough to tell you what to do, but I can give you some general advice:

1. If you need a component on the page (e.g. an interactive visualization of data) try to find an off-the-shelf plugin.
2. If an off-the-shelf plugin is unavailable, write the component in the form of a plugin. This ties in well with jQuery's design and ensures a high degree of reusability.
3. Try to separate the Javascript from the HTML. Typically your HTML is a page full of ids or classes that can be used as "mount points" for the Javascript to link into. The Javascript file would typically look like this:

   $(document).ready(function() {

   // Start making AJAX calls, setting up page

   // elements, and whatever else you need.

   });
4. Given that the Javascript is tied to the page, try to keep the number of pages down while giving each page its own Javascript file. If a page is particularly complicated or makes use of reusable include files, separate the Javascript into smaller files that control only a portion of the page. There can be as many $(document).ready() calls as you need.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help, your advice makes a lot of sense. I'm trying to avoid writing JS code that is fragmented...meaning it has a repeatable pattern to it (generally speaking). I don't want to get into the habit of just calling methods and assigning them to selectors.

I wonder if it would make sense to build all the HTML mount points in an initializer function. Then once all the elements are present, start loading individual parts of the app: menu, data tables, details view, etc...

Do you have any advice on "scaffolding" a JS project?

Comment: This gets into some of the difficulties of your specific situation. If you're trying to create a desktop-like app, then you'll probably want to divide your JS code into a file per major component. If you're looking at components that are repeated from page to page, put the repeatable stuff in its own JS file vs. the page's JS file. If you're architecting toward drop-in components, align your JS with the drop-in components. In short, do what makes the most logical sense to you. And if what you've done doesn't make sense, refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Once your JS is completed, in production have it minified:

http://jscompress.com/

Also, if you use multiple jquery addons such as jquery UI, keep them all under the same file for faster performance.